# Why is Bootstrap Table plugin is not working this example?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am trying to use this [Bootstrap Table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/index.html) with the Bootstrap 2.3. However, I could not get the sorting mechanism of this plugin in the table I have here while I followed all the instructions mentioned in the [Demos page](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#basic-table) of its website.

**So how can I get this sorting mechanism working in IE9?**

The table should be sorted via the first column.

Code:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="id" data-sort-order="desc" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Exercise</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Exercise Code</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Initiated by</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Initiated on</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Done by</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Q1</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Q2</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Q3</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Q4</th>
                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            John
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Maria
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Sam
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                        </td>
                        <td>For Action
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's what I have in the head of the page: (Please note that I am developing an ASP.NET application):

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/custom_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js") %>"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-table.min.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: Are you saying that it only fails in IE9?

Comment: Looks like they are trying to sort based on user-input. I don't think that is a correct application of the framework.

Comment: if you want to sort user input, I think you change input field to plain text when user finished their work.

Comment: I can't guess anything your asp source. I don't know your source path.
Can you show me the final html source on browser?

Answer (score 1):

It works well.
In my opinion, you must missed something over table .
script or link syntax or maybe import order.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.4.0/bootstrap-table.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.4.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="id" data-sort-order="desc">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Exercise</th>
      <th class="text-center">Exercise Code</th>
      <th class="text-center">Initiated by</th>
      <th class="text-center">Initiated on</th>
      <th class="text-center">Done by</th>
      <th class="text-center">Q1</th>
      <th class="text-center">Q2</th>
      <th class="text-center">Q3</th>
      <th class="text-center">Q4</th>
      <th class="text-center"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        John
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Maria
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Sam
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini span1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
      </td>
      <td>For Action
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you kindly check my updated question? Also, please note that I have to use Bootstrap 2.3

Comment: I'm not a ASP developer. Can you show your code for me actual runtime on browser? After that we can solve it together.